# Current class on permalink in loop

Tags: wordpress

Iv'e got a very small loop that sits on the left of a content part of the site. It lists permalinks from a post-type called "news". It acts as a navigation.

I want, just as in wp_nav_menu, to add a current class when the post is being viewed.

**Code in nav part:**

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news'
    );

    $advloop = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<ul>

<?php if ( $advloop -> have_posts() ) : while ( $advloop->have_posts() ) : $advloop -> the_post(); ?>

    <li class="clearfix">

        <div class="postDate"><?php the_time('d-m-Y'); ?></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    </li>


<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

On the right there is another WP_Query for retrieving the post itself. All works like it should, just can't seem to figure out how te get that current class in the left loop.

My PHP is not so great but I find my way around the WP codex.

**The query in the content part:**

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'loops/news', 'loop' ); ?>

<article class="content">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { 
        $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large'); 
        echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" class="popup-link pull-right newsFI" >';
        the_post_thumbnail('large');
        echo '</a>';
        } ?>                        

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

</article>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT [SOLUTION]**

Aha! Stupid me, pretty easy after I gave it some more thought:

```
$current_id = $post->ID;

<a <?php if ( $current_class ) echo $current_class; ?> href="<?php the_permalink()
```

Comment: +1 for making efforts on your own and sharing the fix then